# How to recursively select binary data split over multiple rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sitecore

Having read many similar questions on here, please let me say to start with that I did not choose to split the data (Sitecore did) and all I'm trying to do is recombine it so I can extract binary files from the blobs table.  Therefore answers telling me I shouldn't be splitting data in the table like this are unlikely to be deemed as sensible responses ;-)

Pic of table data (obviously the data is not as shown, I did that for speed)
[image]

Some items are only split over 1 to 3 entries. Some are up to 178 entries!

At present I have a manual process that works, but I'd have to do an awful lot of conditional statement repetition to make it work for the bigger files.  I'm hoping there's a smarter way to do a subquery, union or join that allows it to be done for any file from 1 to 178 rows.

```
SELECT it.name,sf.itemID, it.templateId,
CASE WHEN EXISTS(select 1 from Sitecore2018.dbo.Blobs bl where bl.[Index] = 2 and bl.BlobId = sf.value)
        THEN
            (select cast(bl.Data as Varbinary(max)) from Sitecore2018.dbo.Blobs bl where bl.[Index] = 0 and bl.BlobId = sf.value) +
            (select cast(bl.Data as Varbinary(max)) from Sitecore2018.dbo.Blobs bl where bl.[Index] = 1 and bl.BlobId = sf.value) +
            (select cast(bl.Data as Varbinary(max)) from Sitecore2018.dbo.Blobs bl where bl.[Index] = 2 and bl.BlobId = sf.value) 
        ELSE 
            CASE WHEN EXISTS(select 1 from Sitecore2018.dbo.Blobs bl where bl.[Index] = 1 and bl.BlobId = sf.value)
            THEN
                (select cast(bl.Data as Varbinary(max)) from Sitecore2018.dbo.Blobs bl where bl.[Index] = 0 and bl.BlobId = sf.value) +
                (select cast(bl.Data as Varbinary(max)) from Sitecore2018.dbo.Blobs bl where bl.[Index] = 1 and bl.BlobId = sf.value) 
            ELSE 
            (select bl.Data from Sitecore2018.dbo.Blobs bl where bl.[Index] = 0 and bl.BlobId = sf.value ) 
            END
        END  as BData    
  FROM [Sitecore2018].[dbo].[Items] it
  inner join Sitecore2018.dbo.SharedFields sf on sf.ItemId = it.id
  where 
  it.TemplateID='0603F166-35B8-469F-8123-E8D87BEDC171' 
  and 
  sf.FieldId='40E50ED9-BA07-4702-992E-A912738D32DC' 
  and (sf.value is not null and sf.Value != '')
  order by it.name asc
```

Comment: What's the ultimate fate of the data? Recombining the blobs in client code would be fairly trivial, and it wouldn't even need additional memory -- just `order by index` and loop over that stuff with a stream. Doing it in T-SQL, though -- nightmarish, and certainly not efficient.

Comment: Has to be SQL as I'm using SQL image viewer to batch extract hundreds of binary files from the database and it needs a working SQL statement that has a "Varbinary(max)" field for the data it extracts.  The manual version I posted works for items up to 3 rows long.

Comment: Sure, it works -- as long as you take into account that SQL Server actually concatenates these things in memory. I don't know how large each blob is, but if done recursively (or even with a cursor) those 178 rows for that one entry are going to produce a ton of memory churn. Keep an eye out if you're doing it on a production box. (I'm too lazy to set up a DB and actually write the query; recursive CTEs make my head hurt.)

Comment: Sort of thing I'd do in the front end..

Comment: The front end of sql image viewer, which is a bit of software I'm using for batch processing hundreds of these...? Thanks. If I wanted a custom software code solution I'd have asked for one of those.  As it is, I'd like to know if it can be done in T-SQL

Comment: @TheMook: Are you able to use the Sitecore API or the package creator to move this data out of the database? A lot of the Sitecore application has utilities to work with the data layer and will be a far more efficient way of extracting the information then attempting to do it yourself via T-SQL.

Comment: I'm doing the query via SQL and using a 3rd party image viewer/saver to batch save the items. All works fine now since I used some info from Shnugo's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somehow tricky, but you might try this:

I use a *mockup-table* to simulate your issue. To show the principles I insert `NVARCHAR`-values.

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, GroupID INT, GroupIndex INT,SomeVal NVARCHAR(100),TheValAsBin VARBINARY(MAX));
INSERT INTO @mockup(GroupId,GroupIndex,SomeVal) VALUES(1,1,N'blah'),(1,2,N'buh'),(1,3,N'oh yeah!')
                                                     ,(2,1,N'&<>§!€'),(2,2,N' 汉语;'),(2,3,N'русский язык'),(2,4,''),(2,5,N'शान्तिः');
```

--Now I update the table to set the corresponding `VARBINARY`-values

```
UPDATE @mockup SET TheValAsBin=CAST(SomeVal AS VARBINARY(MAX));
```

--The recursive CTE will fiddle all these `VARBINARY`-values to one long value.
--You can check the result by converting the cummulated `VARBINARY` back to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

```
WITH RecursiveCTE AS
(
    SELECT GroupId,GroupIndex,TheValAsBin,TheValAsBin AS GrowingValue FROM @mockup WHERE GroupIndex=1 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT m.GroupID,m.GroupIndex,m.TheValAsBin
          ,rc.GrowingValue + ISNULL(m.TheValAsBin, CAST('' AS VARBINARY(MAX))) 
    FROM @mockup m
    INNER JOIN RecursiveCTE rc ON m.GroupID=rc.GroupID AND m.GroupIndex=rc.GroupIndex+1
)
SELECT * 
      ,CAST(GrowingValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS CheckTheResult
FROM RecursiveCTE
ORDER BY GroupID,GroupIndex;
```

At the end you have to pick the row with the highest `GroupIndex` per `GroupId`.

Change the last `SELECT` to this

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES GroupId
                      ,CAST(GrowingValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS CheckTheResult
FROM RecursiveCTE
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY GroupIndex DESC)
```

In order to get this:

```
GroupId CheckTheResult
2       &<>§!€ 汉语;русский языкशान्तिः
1       blahbuhoh yeah!
```

Comment: I had to modify it slightly but that did it, thanks. The bit I was missing from my attempt was ` AND m.GroupIndex=rc.GroupIndex+1` to make it climb up through the index values in order

Comment: @TheMook Glad to help you... Yeah, one must think the *recursive cte* as *iterativ cte* crawling through the set as *hidden RBAR* ,-)